# Is this a bug in LaplaceTransform?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

The following evaluates to $\approx 149.162$ in 13.2 Mathematica. I can't figure out how this value is obtained, every other method returns `Indeterminate` or stays unevaluated.

```
LaplaceTransform[1/t,t,1.]
```

Comment: Same behavior on v12.2.0 on Win7-x64.

Comment: You have version 13.3.2 already? :D

Comment: $VersionNumber  13.2
 LaplaceTransform[1/t, t, 1.]
149.162

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "13.2.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (January 27, 2023)" *)

ClearAll["Global`*"];
```

From the documentation, "LaplaceTransform[f[t], t, Overscript[s, ^]] gives the numeric Laplace transform at the numerical value Overscript[s, ^] ."

The result is highly dependent on the precision used.

```
Table[{wp, LaplaceTransform[1/t, t, SetPrecision[1, wp]]},
 {wp, {MachinePrecision, 5, 10, 15, 20, Infinity}}]
```

[image]

```
Table[{wp, 
   NIntegrate[1/t E^(-s*t), {t, 0, Infinity}, WorkingPrecision -> wp] /. 
    s -> SetPrecision[1, wp]}, {wp, {MachinePrecision, 5, 10, 15, 20, 
    Infinity}}] // Quiet
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I guess I'm still confused as to what the correct result should be

Comment: This does not appear to converge to a value for increasing precision (e.g., `Table[{wp, LaplaceTransform[1/t, t, SetPrecision[1, wp]]}, {wp, 25, 100, 25}]` so I would assume that the result is "does not work for this function"

Comment: Mi Yan of Wolfram Support replied that it's intended behavior. Although I personally think a better behavior would be to return unevaluated

Answer (score 1):

Since I cannot comment yet, replying to the comment "I guess I'm still confused as to what the correct result should be"---the correct result is that this object does not exist: The Laplace transform of 1/t is not defined at any point (without a regulator or something similar).

As pointed out in the answer by Bob Hanlon, the numerical answer you get is simply a byproduct of poor numerical accuracy, and I imagine its value holds no deeper meaning whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

There is not only one bug in LaplaceTransform in vs 13.

vs 6:

```
  Limit[Exp[-x t]/t ,{t,y, Infinity}, Assumptions-> {x>0}],y->0]
  -EulerGamma -Log[x]
```

The same with
LaplaceTransform[1/t, t , 1.0]
-EulerGamma

Similar bugs exist in InverseLaplaceTransform and at other complex corners. I suppose, that somebody tried to implant logical decision making and AI instead of good old table lookup for integrals.

But the discussion of presenting complex integrals in Mathematica persists in groups confronted with the results and able to check them, now since 28 years at least.